# How to center a logotype and a menu with singularitygs

Tags: html, sass, singularitygs

I want to center two elements in a header  with singularity. This is the html code I have

```
<div class="l-branding">


<div class="l-region l-region--branding">
        <div class="block block--block block--block-5" id="block-block-5">
            <div class="block__content">
         <p><a target="_self" href="http://somoscoatepec.com"><img width="280" height="139" title="" alt="logotipo" src="http://somoscoatepec.com/sites/default/files/logocoate.png"></a></p>
       </div>
</div>
<nav class="block block--system block--menu block--system-main-menu" role="navigation" id="block-system-main-menu">

  <ul class="menu">
      <li class="first leaf"><a title="menu" href="/section">menu element</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/que-hacer">menu element</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/que-ver">menu element</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/que-comprar">menu element</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/hoteles-y-restaurantes">menu element</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/blog">menu element</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a title="" href="/contact">menu element</a></li>

</ul>

    </nav>

  </div>

    </div>
```

And the sass code I have is:

```
// layout



 $grids: 12;
 $gutters: 5px;

// branding and logotype in  #block-block-5 

 .l-branding  {


                           @include grid-span(12,1);
                          padding: 0 0 0 5px;
                           clear:both;
                           background-color: #492527 ;

                                   #block-block-5    {
                                   @include grid-span(8, 6);
                                    //background-color: #492527;
                                    padding-top:10px;
                                    clear:right;

                                   } 

                           }

// main menu
#block-system-main-menu {

    @include grid-span(8, 5);
    background-color: #492527;
    height:100%;
    z-index:10;

}
```

So I try to find if there is a better solution to center elements.

the logotype is in the id #block-block-5 
and the menu with the id #block-system-main-menu

the menu is the big problem, because dont adjust no matter is begin in the four or five column in any case there is a little extra space and never get in the center. Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Please add a http://SassMeister.com example of your code to the post, then write a follow-up comment for me to notice your edit.

Comment: I paste some of the code and dont see like in the page http://sassmeister.com/gist/e674f47e8593dbef2f52  you can see the final result in this page somoscoatepec.com see the logotype and main menu.

Comment: Oh, come on, man. Sort it out. Select proper Sass version (3.2) in SassMeister settings, remove unavailable imports, strip HTML code of messy Drupal classes, format HTML and Sass carefully, etc. We're here to answer questions about Singularity, not to do dirty work for you.

Comment: Your task is to produce a MINIMAL demo of your issue. Don't copy-paste half of your messy Drupal website, reproduce it from scratch.

Comment: I only want to center two divs and know if there is a better way to center  with  @include grid-span(,); or with out it. I dont need someone to check for free all my site Sass, dont be rude.